# How to using th:if tag to check database field using thymeleaf

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-el

i am new to spEL and i want to use the "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Exams;" query with JPQL or spEL to check if the record in the database is less than 6(six); 
This is what i have. I can not really figure out how to go about it because i am not able to use the @Query annotation in the controller.

```
 //Problem writing spEL
<div class="form-group" th:if="${exams.count(*) < 6}" >
<form method="post"  th:object="${newExam}" th:action="@{/exams}" class="inline new-item">
    <label class="form-control input-sm"><input type="text" th:field="*{indexNumber}" placeholder="Index Number" autocomplete="off"/></label>
    <select th:field="*{grade}" class="form-control input-sm">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled">[Select Grade]</option>
        <option th:each="grade : ${grades}" th:value="${grade.values}" th:text="${grade.name}">Grade</option>
    </select>
    <label class="form-control input-sm"><input type="text" th:field="*{courseOffered}" placeholder="CourseOffered"  autocomplete="off"/></label>
    <label class="form-control input-sm"><input type="text" th:field="*{examType}" placeholder="ExamType" autocomplete="off"/></label>
    <label class="form-control input-sm"><input type="text" th:field="*{subject}" placeholder="Subject"  autocomplete="off"/></label>
    <label class="form-control input-sm datepicker"><input type="text" th:field="*{gradeYear}" placeholder="ExamYear"  autocomplete="off"/></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

---

```
@Controller
public class ExamsController {

    @Autowired
    private ExamService examService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/cert_prog")
    public String examsList(Model model){
        Iterable<Exams> exams = examService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("exams", exams);
        model.addAttribute("newExam", new Exams());
        model.addAttribute("grades", Grade.values());
        return "cert_prog";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/mark", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String toggleComplete(@RequestParam Long id) {
        Exams exams = examService.findOne(id);
        examService.toggleComplete(id);
        return "redirect:/cert_prog";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/exams", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addTask(@ModelAttribute Exams exams, Principal principal){
        //User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        User user = (User)((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)principal).getPrincipal();
        exams.setUser(user);
        //examService.increment(exams);
        examService.save(exams);
        return "redirect:/cert_prog";
    }
}
```

---

@Service
public class ExamServiceImpl implements ExamService {

```
@Autowired
private ExamsDao examsDao;

@Override
public Iterable<Exams> findAll() {
    return examsDao.findAll();
}

@Override
public Exams findOne(Long id) {
    return examsDao.findOne(id);
}

@Override
public void toggleComplete(Long id) {
    Exams exams = examsDao.findOne(id);
    exams.setComplete(!exams.isComplete());
    examsDao.save(exams);
}

@Override
public void save(Exams exams) {
    examsDao.save(exams);
}

@Override
public void increment(Exams exams) {
    //exams.setCounter(exams.getCounter() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to query the DB again. Exams is already an iterable collection of all exam records, isn't it?  Try

```
<div class="form-group" th:if="${exams.size() < 6}" >
```

As long as the underlying class of the Iterable object implements the size() method, thymeleaf should be able to find and call it. Otherwise you'll need to cast to a collection that does implement size before you add the object to the model.

Comment: Thanks @geneSummons. When i use that script i got Fatal error during parsing org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "th:if" associated with an element type "div" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: This worked <div class="form-group" th:if="${exams.size() lt 6}" >